# how to fill datagridview using oledb in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using vb 10 and access database. In my form, I have a DataGridView and button(for retrieving data from my database).

The problem is when I click the button, there are no data place in my DataGridView. Even if there are data in my database.

I have seen so many codes but it is just the same. I am using OleDb for connection. Thank you so much!

codes(under button_click):

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdTest.Click
    con2.Open()

    sql = "select * from AddressInfo"
    Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    comm.CommandText = sql
    comm.Connection = con2
    da.SelectCommand = comm

    da.Fill(ds, "AddressInfo")
    DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables("AddressInfo").DefaultView
    con2.Close()
    MsgBox("Success", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try and set a break point on `DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables("AddressInfo").DefaultView` and hover over `Tables` is there anything?

Comment: hi @436f6465786572 this is the line over the tables.

ds.Tables("AddressInfo") = {AddressInfo}